# How to set the file-permissions of a buffer before it's written?

Tags: files, permissions

Is it possible to set the permissions on a buffer before it's written to a file? Or is it necessary to [change the permissions after writing it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29175/2418)?

(technically this would allow some small time-frame for another user to read the file, I would rather avoid this).

---

Note that this is for a package that writes files, so I rather not change the default system/emacs wide.

Comment: Not sure what the scenario is: who is the owner of the emacs process? Is there a shared directory that it is writing into? Why can't you have private directories? All of this seems more appropriate to Unix & Linux SE than to Emacs SE.

Comment: The directory isn't shared, it's in `~/.config/emacs` - would this be a case where permissions should be 600?

Comment: So you chmod the directory to 700 and you are done - once and for all.

Comment: When I want to create a new read-only file once in a while  I save it already when it's empty; change the protection of the saved file; and then continue to edit it. The autosave file, the backup file, and the next save will all be protected. It's a bit clumsy perhaps, but is enough if this is something seldom done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your umask so that only your user can read newly–created files. Note that this can be done in the shell before you start Emacs (shells usually provide a command called `umask` for this purpose), or while Emacs is running by calling `set-default-file-modes`. See [chapter 26.7 Changing File Names and Attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Files.html).

Note that all processes have a umask, so you can use this solution with all programs, not just Emacs.

Edit: your modification changes the nature of the question quite significantly. However, if you take another look at [chapter 26.7 Changing File Names and Attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Files.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual, you will find a macro called `with-file-modes` that allows you to do exactly what you want.

Also, NickD’s suggestion to simply change the permissions of the cache directory is a sound one. It doesn’t matter much if the files in a directory are readable or not if other users cannot traverse into it.

Comment: An issue with this is it applies to all files, I'm have a bug report in a package I maintain that cache files should only be readable by the user. (updating question)

Comment: +1 for `with-file-modes`.